# Add a user to a SharePoint site collection using Office 365 Graph API

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office365apis

I need to add a new user to a site collection via the Office 365 Graph API. Is it possible? If so, what would the REST call look like?

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372335/utilize-azure-graph-api-for-sharepoint-online-user-management